# Systemverilog Support in tagbar plugin

Tags: vim, ctags, vim-plugin, exuberant-ctags, tagbar

can anybody help me to add systemverilog language support in tagbar vim plugin.

I tried below things but its doesnt worked for me

1) Created ~/.ctags and copy code from https://github.com/shaohao/config.d/blob/master/ctags

2) mkdir ftplugin to ~/.vim and add systemverilog.vim from https://github.com/shaohao/vimfiles/blob/master/bundle/verilog_systemverilog/ftplugin/systemverilog.vim

3)cd to project directory and run ctags -R *
Got below warning though

```
 ctags: Warning: Unknown language specified in "langmap" option
```

Below are some output of ctags

```
 ctags --list-languages
 ctags: Warning: Unknown language specified in "langmap" option
 .
 .
 systemverilog

 ctags --list-kinds=systemverilog

 ctags: Warning: Unknown language specified in "langmap" option
 e  clocking 
 i  constraint 
 l  covergroup 
 o  class 
 t  function 
 A  interface 
 G  module 
 J  package 
 M  program 
 W  task
```

But still when i open SV file in gvim and use :TagbarToggle tagbar window is blank :(

Please help

Answer (score 2):

I've introduced some improvements to the verilog_systemverilog vim plugin that I made available at [Github](https://github.com/vhda/verilog_systemverilog.vim). You should have proper Tagbar support if you use [this](https://github.com/fishman/ctags) development version of exuberante-ctags together with my vim plugin and the following Tagbar configuration:

```
let g:tagbar_type_verilog_systemverilog = {
        \ 'ctagstype'   : 'SystemVerilog',
        \ 'kinds'       : [
            \ 'b:blocks:1:1',
            \ 'c:constants:1:0',
            \ 'e:events:1:0',
            \ 'f:functions:1:1',
            \ 'm:modules:0:1',
            \ 'n:nets:1:0',
            \ 'p:ports:1:0',
            \ 'r:registers:1:0',
            \ 't:tasks:1:1',
            \ 'A:assertions:1:1',
            \ 'C:classes:0:1',
            \ 'V:covergroups:0:1',
            \ 'I:interfaces:0:1',
            \ 'M:modport:0:1',
            \ 'K:packages:0:1',
            \ 'P:programs:0:1',
            \ 'R:properties:0:1',
            \ 'T:typedefs:0:1'
        \ ],
        \ 'sro'         : '.',
        \ 'kind2scope'  : {
            \ 'm' : 'module',
            \ 'b' : 'block',
            \ 't' : 'task',
            \ 'f' : 'function',
            \ 'C' : 'class',
            \ 'V' : 'covergroup',
            \ 'I' : 'interface',
            \ 'K' : 'package',
            \ 'P' : 'program',
            \ 'R' : 'property'
        \ },
    \ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Background: TagBar won't use your `tags` file, it queries `ctags` and read its output directly from `stdout`.

I believe the problem is how the `--langmap` is defined in your `~/.ctags`. AFAIK, the coma is used to separate langmaps while different extensions are just put one after the other without separators:

```
--langmap=foo:.foo.fo.oo,bar:.bar.ba
```

I think line 2 of your `~/.ctags` file should look like this:

```
--langmap=systemverilog:.sv.svh.svp
```

Comment: Thank you :) with above change warning is gone! but what about adding support in tagbar!

Comment: TagBar is supposed to honor the definitions in your `~/.ctags` when running `ctags` against your code. If you still have problems I suggest you try TagBar's issue tracker.

Comment: didnt get you? tagbar is not working for me with above changes even with warning fix.

Comment: Yes, I got you, but this is not tagbar's issue tracker.